# populating state dropdown from country selection in asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

i have an old classic asp application that need to update.  i need to add 2 dropdowns and the second one needs to be populated based on the first (ex.  country and states).  how do you do that using javascript?

Comment: Create a asp page which takes countryid as parameter in query string and use xmlhttprequest to do asynchronous request.

Comment: i don't suppose you have example code for doing this?

Comment: I had implemented this type of requirement while I was working on ASP (vbscript) long time back. At that time, there were no client side librarires like JQuery, so used XmlHttprequest on client side and regular ASP page which took "id" parameter.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Based on your comment below, I've updated my response to include code that will do what you're wanting. You can use the `optgroup` element to filter `options` based on what country is selected without having to use Ajax.

**First way: (optgroup filtering)**

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/5STCN/).

HTML:

```
<select id="C_Country" name="C_Country" aria-required="true" class="required">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="USA">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
</select>
<p>
    <label for="C_State_Prov">State or Province <span title="required">*</span>
    </label>
</p>
<select id="C_State_Prov" name="C_State_Prov" aria-required="true" class="required">
    <option value="" selected="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <optgroup label="United States">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Canada">
        <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
        <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var state_province = $('#C_State_Prov option, #C_State_Prov optgroup');

state_province.hide();

$('#C_Country').change(function () {
    state_province.hide();
    $("#C_State_Prov optgroup[label='" + $(this).find(':selected').html() + "']")
        .children()
        .andSelf()
        .show();
});
```

**Second way: (Ajax)**

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/8RbtW/).

Here's a rough idea of how to accomplish this. The URL defined in the jQuery should point to a location where the server-side code will generate the HTML needed based on the country the user selected (instead of being defined as a variable in the JavaScript).

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <div>
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="country" id="country">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="us">United States</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="stateContainer" class="hidden">
        <div>
            <label for="state">State</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id="state" name="state"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $country = $("#country"),
    $stateContainer = $("#stateContainer"),
    $state = $("#state"),
    url = "http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/KZ4jd/",
    html = '<option value="al">Alabama</option><option value="ar">Arkansas</option>',
    countryVal;

$country.change(function () {
    countryVal = $country.val();
    $stateContainer.show();
    $state.html(html).load(loadUrl);
});
```

Comment: sorry, i'm don't understand javascript very well.  if i have a country dropdown popualted and the dropdown for all the possible states in the states dropdown populated, how do i filter it?  isn't that all i need to do.  i just have no idea how to filter in javascript.  i'm assuming i'd have my state value be something like <option value="us|al">Alabama</option>....i'd have to split it and only show the US states when selected.  does that make sense?